# how to run a script as soon as two separate functions become available?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

On my test site I am trying to load some text about the video using AJAX before the user switches videos then input the text after the ajax returns successfully.

I need to check if both the AJAX has returned successfully and a javascript function has become available. How can I check this?

I can separately run a function as soon as the AJAX has loaded and as soon as the javascript function have become available but i do not know which order they will come in.

Comment: What do you mean by the javascript function becoming available?  What's the mechanism you will use to detect that?

Comment: *become available* -- if possible you should have that other function trigger an event/callback of some kind.

Comment: I am using slides.js and i cant use a callback because i do not know which function will come back first.

Comment: But you have two callbacks from two functions? Please show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something with events and callbacks. I'm still not sure what you mean by **"function has become available"**, but here is something off the top of my head that should get your started.

```
// Check if all conditions are complete.
function completionChecker(limit, callback) {
  // Private count variable will outlast scope due to closure.
  var count = 0;
  // Return a callback for the event.
  return function(event) {
    if(++count == limit) { 
      // Call the callback supplied.
      callback(); 
      // Remove the event listener, we've reached the limit.
      this.removeEventListener("finished", arguments.callee, false); 
    }
  }      
}

// Some function to perform when everything is complete.
function myFunc() { /* Do stuff */ }

// Create a custom event.
var myEvt = new CustomEvent("finished");
// Add a listener to the document. After 2 "finished" events, call myFunc.
document.addEventListener("finished", completionChecker(2, myFunc), false);

// Now in your ajax success callback, and wherever your other function 
// has "become available", fire the "finished" event.
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```